# Removing a Frame from a Vertical-Panel

Tags: gwt, mvp

I need some help with removing a [`Frame`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html) from a [`VerticalPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/VerticalPanel.html)

- I have a GWT Module in which I also used HISTORY.
- I am using the MVP framework so I have initialized my mainPanel which
  is a Vertical Panel of GWT.
- I have added a Hyperlink to the main panel.
- I have now added a Frame to that Panel.

After a few methods, I am trying to clear the Panel in order to reuse it.

When I call the clear method of the main panel, I see that the hyperlink stays the same, and that the Frame is now empty, but both are still showing on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can call clear() on your VerticalPanel, or you can call removeFromParent() on these widgets.